# Char array to unsigned short conversion issue

Tags: c, arrays, casting, char, iar

I am trying to convert char array to unsigned short but its not working as it should.

```
char szASCbuf[64] = "123456789123456789123456789";

int StoreToFlash(char szASCbuf[], int StartAddress)
{   
int iCtr;
int ErrorCode = 0;
int address = StartAddress;
unsigned short *us_Buf = (unsigned short*)szASCbuf;         

// Write to flash
for(iCtr=0;iCtr<28;iCtr++)
{   
    ErrorCode = Flash_Write(address++, us_Buf[iCtr]);
    if((ErrorCode &0x45)!= 0)
    {
      Flash_ClearError();          
    }
}
return ErrorCode;
}
```

When I see the Conversion, on `us_Buf[0]` I have value `12594, us_Buf[1]= 13108 like that and I have values only upto`us_Buf[5]` after that it is "0" all remaining address.
I have tried to declare char array like this also

```
char szASCbuf[64] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1',.....'\0'};
```

I am passing the parameters to function like this

```
StoreToFlash(szASCbuf, FlashPointer); //Flashpointe=0
```

I am using IAR embedded workbench for ARM. Big enedian 32.
Any suggestions where i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have `szASCbuf` as global variable and function parameter in the same time? If yes - this is wrong.

Comment: Out of topic: FYI: `char szASCbuf[64] = {'1','2','3', '\0'}` is strictly the same as `char szASCbuf[64] = "123"`.

Comment: Show the parrt where you call `StoreToFlash` and the relevant surrounding lines.

Comment: It is not very clear how exactly you got {12594, 14136} out of ASCII "1234". 12594 corresponds to "12" and 14136 corresponds to "78".

Comment: on ARM misaligned access is prohibited. You must either access the bytes individually then combine into short or make sure that the char array is properly aligned

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: That is not necessarily true. For Cortex-M3/4 at least you can allow unaligned accesses (but you should not as these are cycle killers).

Answer (score 2):

Reinterpreting the `char` array `szASCbuf` as an array of `short` is not safe because of alignment issues. The `char` type has the least strict alignment requirements and `short` is usually stricter. This means that `szAscBuf` might start at address `13`, whereas a `short` should start at either `12` or `14`.

This also violates the strict aliasing rule, since `szAscBuf` and `us_Buf` are pointing at the same location while having different pointer types. The compiler might perform optimisations which don't take this into account and this could manifest in some very nasty bugs.

The correct way to write this code is to iterate over the original `szASCBuf` with a step of 2 and then do some bit-twiddling to produce a 2-byte value out of it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(szAscbuf); i += 2) {
    uint16_t value = (szAscbuf[i] << 8) | szAscbuf[i + 1];
    ErrorCode = Flash_Write(address++, value);

    if (ErrorCode & 0x45) {
        Flash_ClearError();          
    }
}
```

If you really intended to treat the digit characters with their numeric value, this will do it:

```
uint16_t value = (szAscbuf[i] - '0') + (szAscbuf[i + 1] - '0');
```

In case you just want the numeric value of each character in a 2-byte value (1, 2, 3, 4, ...), iterate over the array with a step of 1 and fetch it this way:

```
uint16_t value = szAscbuf[i] - '0';
```

Comment: You mean convert szASCbuf to integer value before assingning to unsgined short.

Comment: I prefer to use `uint16_t` because it is explicit about its size. `unsigned short` isn't strictly guaranteed to be 2 bytes on every platform.

Comment: If possible can give some example how to do that?

Comment: i have tried as you metioned but still i have diffrent values in "value" rather than 1,2,3,4....from szASCBuf. I have values like 12594, 12851,13108,13365. I have declared char szASCbuf[64]="123456789"; then i should have values in "value" like 1,2,3,4,5...

Answer (score 0):

That's normal !

Your char array is  `"123456789123456789123456789"` or  `{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1',.....'\0'}`

But in ASCII `'1'` is `0x31`, so when you read the array as a `short *` on a big endian architecture, it gives :

```
{ 0x3132, 0x3334, ... }
```

say differently in decimal :

```
{ 12594, 13108, ... }
```

Comment: I have only 5 values like that after that it is "0" for the NeXT 24 address.?

Comment: @verendra : what are your 5 values ? and how do you call ` StoreToFlash` ?

Comment: like {12594, 13108, 13631, 14136, 0, 0 ,0 ...} like that.I am calling "StoreToFlash" like StoreToFlash(szASCbuf, FlashPointer); //Flashpointe=0. I have edited my post With how i am calling that function.

Comment: @verendra : then you are pointing to a string containing "12345?78". I cannot explain why, but you should try to print it in your function to control that ...